# Resize window and window form

Tags: vb.net, resize

I want to be able to resize my form. I'm using :
[at launch]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIaQx.jpg (i launch it like so, it's working as intendend for now)

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
```

when i maximize using : [maximized] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc2mZ.jpg (still working as intendend)

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```

i can't put it back to the normal size it hides every buttons or Data grid that i've set. Or just doesn't resize at all and just moves from full screen to windowed [back to "minimized"] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgNKg.jpg (now it's weird)

I'm looking for a way to do it properly.

Also wanted to know if there is a way to automate it because i'm using buttons on my form to resize the whole window and wanted to use the top bar of the window to do it automatically.

Comment: The code you have shown is equivalent to clicking the Restore Down and Maximise buttons respectively on the title bar of your form. If you want to maximise and restore then that is the correct code. If that's not what you want to do then why use that code in the first place? If you want to change the size of the form then the obvious thing to do is to set the `Size` of the form, or the `Width` or `Height` if you only want to resize in one direction. It's not clear that that's the issue either though. Maybe you could provide a screenshot or two to clarify your rather vague description.

Comment: I think you want the _controls_ to be resized with the form, am I correct? If so, you might want to check the [`Dock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock) and [`Anchor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor) properties and you might consider using a `TableLayoutPanel` to organize your controls. Also, you might want to [edit] the question and include a screenshot of your form so we can give you a better advice.

Comment: Judging by the screenshots, it looks like you're using some (faulty) code to resize the controls. Don't do that. Instead, resize the controls manually at design-time to fill the whole form (or however you want them to be) and then set the `Anchor` property of the DataGridView to `Top, Bottom, Left, Right`, set the `Anchor` property of the top-left buttons to `Top, Left`, the bottom-left buttons to `Bottom, Left`, and the right buttons to `Bottom, Right`. Get rid of any code that resizes the controls and you should be good to go.

Comment: As suggested, you should not be using code to resize controls with the form except in very specific  circumstances. It should all happen automatically if you configure them correctly. [Here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?630636)'s one I prepared earlier.

Comment: @jmcilhinney @Ahmed i tried your method like so : 
`dgv.Anchor = Top , Bottom , Left , Right`
but is expecting an end of instruction at the first "," do you know why ?

Comment: @FoxLeCredule No, don't change it using code. Change it manually at design-time (find the `Anchor` property on the Properties window). That being said, If you want to know how to change it in code, it would be `dgv.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Right`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to the help of @Ahmed AbdelHameed and @jmcilhinney, I fixed my problem by simply using the anchor in the design section of my form.